# Make focusout event ignore some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-focusout

In the code below if you click on `<input type="text" id="one" />` and a "red block" *appears*. If you focus out then the "red block" *disappears*.

How do I make it so that `focusout` wont fire if "red block" or `<input type="text" id="two" />` are the next focused elements?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukve6/2/)

**JavaScript**

```
$('#one').focus(function () {
    $('#divRemove').show();
});

$('#one').focusout(function () {
    $('#divRemove').hide();
});

$('#divRemove').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="one" />_______
<input type="text" id="two" />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="divRemove" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red; display:none;">remove on focus out</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the focus on both #one and #two

```
$('#one,#two').focus(function () {
    $('#divRemove').show();
}).focusout(function () {
    $('#divRemove').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/ukve6/4/)

**Update**

You can't really focus a div unless you give it a custom index like this with `tabindex="0"`

```
<div id="divRemove" tabindex="0"
```

and then in jQuery do this

```
$('#one,#two,#divRemove').focus(function () {
    $('#divRemove').show();
}).focusout(function () {
    $('#divRemove').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/ukve6/6/)

Comment: great thanks so much - one more thing what if the red div had other elements in it. would that apply toall its children to no close?

Comment: `+1` although you could chain the event handlers to avoid repeating the selector

Comment: @Hello-World i think so, it should not be a problem

Comment: hi - can you help with this please - if I put elements in the div then it closes on the second element in focus - thanks  http://jsfiddle.net/ukve6/8/

Comment: @Hello-World Take away focusout for `oneA,oneB,oneC` like this http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/ukve6/10/